# Table Layout and dynamic two text view in table row

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, tablelayout

Hello everyone actually in my android app i am implementing TableLayout.I declared TableLayout in my xml file as follows.

```
     <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
```

and i am trying to display dynamic TableRow and in every row there are two dynamic textview

Following is my code of dynamic table row addition.

```
     split1=new String[split.length];
        split2=new String[split.length];
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
        for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
        {
            String aa=split[i];
            String [] aaa=aa.split(" : ");
            split1[i]=aaa[0];
            split2[i]=aaa[1];
            TableRow row=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            TableLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
            TextView tvDebt=new TextView(Sublimation_ItemView.this);
            TextView tv=new TextView(Sublimation_ItemView.this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(
                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tvDebt.setText("" + split1[i]);
            tv.setText("  :  " + split2[i]);
            row.addView(tvDebt);
            row.addView(tv);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            tvDebt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);

            table.addView(row);
        }
```

The main problem is that my tv textview is not wrapping according to the text.
then how to set height for dynamic textview
following the image that actually display.

[image: Dynamic TextView with multiline]

Comment: you are talking about which TextView?

Comment: TextView tv=new TextView(Sublimation_ItemView.this);

Comment: see package size text it doesnt come at next line